# Screen size supporting from xml?

Tags: android, user-interface

Supporting multiple screen is most important thing is android i think.We are doing some view different size.I know it is basic but i am curious about that.

For example i do a Edittext and i give width 200 dip for 480X800 screen.When i run this project 240X320 screen it will seen too big.We can fix this problem image with the drawable folder but how can we fix it view this problem?I know we can give wrap_content but when we give dip it is bad? When we give dip what is best effort from scale?

THX.

Comment: for margin left or right

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your problem. Do you want to scale views or drawables? For views you can set them dynamically with density scale indeed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530914/how-to-i-develop-android-application-to-work-in-different-screen-resolutions/8531010#8531010

Comment: İ am problem with views.Like button,textview etc.When i get dip android can resize all screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like with `drawables`, you can create different folders with layouts for different screen sizes.
As long as you keep the names of the files consistent across the folders, Android will manage picking the right one automatically.

Just create folders such as:

```
res/layout-small
res/layout-medium
res/layout-large
res/layout-small-land (incase you want landscape mode as well)
```

However, this does mean you will need to manually make adjustments for all screen sizes. Like in your example of the `EditText`, you will need to manually set the size to `100dp` for example in the small screen layout.

Comment: hmm interesting.When i set the size 300 dip edittext and put the all of them.When i use small screen can i see the edittext resize or ican see too big?

Comment: It will still be too big then. It will simply use 300 dip even on the small screen, because you defined it to be 300 dip in a small layout. Hence why you will need to create a smaller layout for smaller screens etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use wrap_content, fill_parent.
You can see layout_weight parameter of linearlayout where you can give value in %. But remember to give ur height or width as 0dp when you are using layout_weight.