# Screen Size in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i have created an application in android but when i test my application on different screen sizes android phones then look and feel is not stable.

My question is how to set your application display for all android phones?

Comment: This question has been answered many times here on SO. I think I answered it once yesterday.

This is what you want: [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Also, use google.

Comment: use different drawable. dont hard cord your layout. use relative layout.................

Comment: k,padma i firstly test my application on samsung galaxy y phone,where it works fine,but when i tried same on samsung tab then its not looks so good,i want to provide global access to my application,so that every android can use it in same looks,i want to remove screen size dependency from my application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Screen size supporting from xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588008/screen-size-supporting-from-xml)

Answer (score 2):

```
 Android has included support for three screen-size “buckets” since 1.6,
based on these “dp” units: “normal” is currently the most popular device format (originally 320x480, more recently higher-density 480x800); 
“small” is for smaller screens, and “large” is for “substantially larger” screens. 
Devices that fall in the “large” bucket include the Dell Streak and original 7” Samsung Galaxy Tab. 
Android 2.3 introduced a new bucket size “xlarge”, in preparation for the approximately-10” tablets (such as the Motorola Xoom) that Android 3.0 was designed to support.

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp.

large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp.

normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp.

small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp.
(Android does not currently support screens smaller than this.)
```

Comment: its ok,but how to define these permission in single application,so that every Android mobile can use my app either their screen size,small,large,normal and xlarge,please show through code.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use relative layout instead of hardcode values like layout_height = "20dp"
or else use two types of layouts 1 each for landscape & portrait, this should solve maximus of your issues. but there is another way to get exactly the same for every screen, by dynamically setting the view attributes...this was

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

```
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button1.setWidth(width / 2);
    Button2.setWidth(width / 2);
```